# I/O Error on LG GSA-H12N DVD drive on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dvd, burning

I am facing an **I/O Error** when I try to *burn* DVD data discs on my **LG GSA-H12N DVD drive** on **Windows 7**. Note that I was able to do this same operation on the same hardware/software just a day earlier without any problems, *but* with Windows XP. The only change (AFAIK) has been the installation of Windows 7 to replace Windows XP on this PC.

Here is the error I get when I try to burn a DVD data disc using **[CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/)** 4.2.7.1801:

[image]

> **Burning error occured**
>
> An error occured while burning the disc. Most likely the disc is not usable.
>   Usually these errors happen if the inserted media is not compatible to the drive or of poor quality.
>
> (devNTSPTI_IO_Error) Could not write to Disc (LBA: 52864 Length: 32).
>
> SCSI Pass-through Interface I/O Error. - 0xFF045D

Note that there can be no problem with the discs since I have been using the same discs (from the same box) just before the Windows 7 installation with no problems. The only change has been Windows 7.

I tried **[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)** v0.5 and **[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)** v2.5 and got similar I/O errors:

[image]

Note that Windows 7 lists the LG GSA-H21N drive as being **compatible** (see [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=LG%20Electronics%20GSA-H12N%20DVD%20Burner&v=LG%20ELECTRONICS&uid=GSA-H12N&pf=5&pi=1&c=Storage%20Devices&sc=CD%2fRW%20%2f%20DVD%2fRW&os=32-bit)).

I also checked the LG Drivers website and using the firware update from there updated the drive firmware from version **UL01** to **UL02**. But, even this has not helped. The drive reads DVDs without any problem, but continues to produce coasters.

[image]

Could someone help me figure out what is the problem? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you since tried it with another operating system (e.g. live CD of Ubuntu)?

Comment: Breakthrough: That is something I could try. But, switching between the Ubuntu Live CD and DVD to be burnt on the CD/DVD drive might become a hassle though.

Comment: I have a similar problem: http://superuser.com/questions/93168/double-layer-dvdr-burning-problem-i-o-error

Comment: Well..get a dvd writer not a "not-writer" (okay for me it just threw out the discs spinning when I pressed the button and one also hit me. Cute machine indeed but wouldn't use it for serious things.)? Like ASUS, Plextor, Pioneer?

Answer (score 2):

I see "DMA speed too slow (ok for 1x)" in the status. If it means what I think it means, this is bad.

Check the DMA setting for you drive in the hardware applet for windows. You can access the mode of the drive by looking at the properties of the IDE/SATA controller the drive is attached to. I don't know the capabilities of that drive, but expect something like DMA 2 or above.

If it is an IDE interface, it might even say PIO mode, which is a fallback mode. This can "break" game encryption schemes resulting in unmountable discs. Resetting to DMA would fix it.

Windows will step down transfer speed of a drive if it has read errors. With CD drives, read errors can bve caused by bad discs, and the counter is never reset, so over time the drive can silently slip into PIO mode. I sort of thought they fixed this in vista, but I never really looked into it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we need an explanation of what 0xFF045D is. But there doesn't seem to be one, so...

Your best bets:

- Have you tried a replacement drive?
- Have you tried contacting LG, CDBurnerXP, InfraRecorder and ImgBurn for more information?
- Have you tried contacting Microsoft or it's support forums?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows XP SP3, all my storage devices were working great until I installed Intel integrated  Ultra ATA Controller.

I found out it is a storage controller that changes all your storage devices (HD-CD-RW-DVD-RW) to SCSI. Ever since then none of my burning software would work, always got "SCSI Pass-Through interface I/O error".

When I uninstalled that driver everything started to work again, the SCSI designation on my drives went back to normal, no more SCSI drives.

You **must uninstall any drivers that change your drives to SCSI**.

Comment: Where in the OP's error message does it say SCSI? I/O errors can mean many things, they are not necessarily related, and since the syntax is very different, it is not likely the same issue.